# Searching for missing or duplicated values in composite keys

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a table with a two-part composite key like the following:

```
Key1  Key2  
a     char1  
a     char2  
a     char3  
a     char4  
a     char5
b     char1 
etc.
```

I need to check if there is a value form Key1 with missing or duplicated corresponding values from Key2 (i.e. values from key1 without 5 specific values from key2). I'm new to sql, thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result! (Same properly formatted text as already used.)

Comment: Instead of "Searching for missing or duplicated values" you may re-think your design by splitting in two tables with single column `PK` each; join then as required...

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From test order by key1, key2;

KEY1 KEY2
---- ----
a    ch1
a    ch2
a    ch3
b    ch1
c    ch2
c    ch3

6 rows selected.
```

One option is to

- create a cross-join of all `[KEY1, KEY2]` combinations
- using `MINUS` set operator, find missing values in the source table

---

```
SQL> with
  2  -- distinct keys
  3  k1 as (select distinct key1 from test),
  4  k2 as (select distinct key2 from test),
  5  -- cross join makes all possible combinations
  6  cj as
  7    (select a.key1, b.key2
  8     from k1 a cross join k2 b
  9    )
 10  -- MINUS set operator returns missing key combinations
 11  select key1, key2 from cj
 12  minus
 13  select key1, key2 from test;

KEY1 KEY2
---- ----
b    ch2
b    ch3
c    ch1

SQL>
```